# PHP MySQL check if items in array exist in Table, THEN SHOW

Tags: php, mysql, database

PHP 5.4 with MySQL
Building off of this:

```
<?php
   $arr = ...
   $sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE field IN ( ' . implode( ',', $arr ) . ' );';
   $result = $db->query( $sql );
?>
```

How would I display which items of the array ARE NOT in the table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of returning the count, return the field itself:

```
$sql = 'SELECT field WHERE field IN ' . implode( ',', $arr ) . ' );';
$result = $db->query($sql);
$found = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $found[] = $row['field'];
}
```

Then you can compare the two arrays:

```
$not_found = array_diff($arr, $found);
```

Comment: You could also `unset` the found items from $arr, and then just display whatever is left.

Comment: You set that earlier in your script, didn't you? It's in `$arr = ...`

Comment: Yeah my bad. So now it shows me every array value, instead of the values that do not exist in the table

Comment: I guess what I'm looking for is: For each item in the array, check to see if it exists in the table. If it doesn't push it to a new array. If it does exists, do not add it to the new array

Comment: That's what `array_diff` does!

Comment: Doing a separate query for each item in the array is a very expensive way to do it. It's better like this, or with the query in @FuzzyTree's answer.

Comment: Ok I see that. Do I still run it through the foreach statement? This time replacing `$arr` for `$not_found`?

Comment: You can do whatever you want with `$not_found`, it's just an array containing all the values that weren't found.

Answer (score 1):

If your `$arr` variable is sanitized and safe to build a query with, you can use `union` operators to build a table containing all the words in the array, then you can left join that table to `table.field` and only keep array items where there was no match.

```
$arr = array('one','two');
$sql = "select item from (
      select '" . implode("' item union select '",$arr). "' item
    ) t1 left join table t2 on t2.field = t1.item
    where t2.field is null";
```

this will produce the following sql

```
select item from (select 'one' item union select 'two' item) t1 
    left join table t2 on t2.field = t1.item
    where t2.field is null
```

Comment: How would I display the data?

Answer (score 0):

Just to give an idea (this probably won't work)

```
$arr = ...
$sql = 'SELECT field FROM table WHERE field IN ( ' . implode( ',', $arr ) . ' );';
$result = $db->query( $sql );
while($r = $result->fetch())
    $arr2[] = $r['field'];
print_r(array_diff($arr,$arr2));
```

Answer (score 0):

after you've done imloud, array ceases to be an array, this is a string, so you do not have to **select count(*)**. You need to select id after do the while and compare arrays

Answer (score 0):

Just use "NOT IN", if your items is up to 10 elements:

```
<?php
   $arr = array('one','two');
   $filterExisting = "'" . implode("', '", $arr ) . "'";
   $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE field NOT IN (". $filterExisting .")";
   $result = $db->query($sql);
?>
```